Why does my CSRF token validation fail when deleting multiple entries in PHP?
I'm encountering an issue with CSRF token validation in my PHP application. Specifically, when I try to delete multiple entries using the same CSRF token, I receive a "CSRF attack detected" error message. I believe this issue is related to the CSRF token being used multiple times within the same session without being regenerated.
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header bg-info">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Are you sure to delete the entry?</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" action="">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($antiXss->xss_clean($_SESSION['auth_token']))); ?>" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="target_id" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="delete_entry" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> delete </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa-solid fa-ban"></i> cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php
session_start();

// Generate a new CSRF token if one doesn't exist
if (!isset($_SESSION['auth_token'])) {
    $_SESSION['auth_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(20));
}

// Handle delete request
if (isset($_POST["delete_entry"])) {
    // Validate CSRF token
    if (!isset($_POST['auth_token']) || !isset($_SESSION['auth_token']) || $_SESSION['auth_token'] !== $_POST['auth_token'] || !isset($_POST['target_id'])) {
        // If the CSRF token is invalid or missing
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <i class="fas fa-bug"></i>
                CSRF attack detected. Please reload the page and try again.<button type="button" class="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>';
        
        // Regenerate CSRF token to prevent any further attempts with the same token
        $_SESSION['auth_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(20));
        exit();
    } else {
        // Proceed with delete operation if the CSRF token is valid
        $target_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($antiXss->xss_clean($_POST['target_id'])));
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM jentress_erp WHERE jnum = ? and company=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $target_id, $_SESSION["company"]);

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $_id = $row["id"];
                $_path = $row["position"]; 
                
                $stmt1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM entress_erp_part2 WHERE contact_id = ?");
                if ($stmt1 === false) {
                    die('Prepare failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
                }
                $stmt1->bind_param("i", $_id);
                $stmt1->execute();
                $result = $stmt1->get_result();
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $_account = htmlspecialchars($antiXss->xss_clean($row['s_account']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        $_acc_serial_token = htmlspecialchars($antiXss->xss_clean($row['acc_serial_token']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        $_debtor = htmlspecialchars($antiXss->xss_clean($row['s_debtor']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        $_creditor = htmlspecialchars($antiXss->xss_clean($row['s_creditor']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

                        $stmtu = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE acc_serial =? AND acc_name=? AND company=?");
                        $stmtu->bind_param("sss", $_acc_serial_token, $_account, $_SESSION["company"]);
                        $stmtu->execute();
                        $resultu = $stmtu->get_result();
                        if ($resultu->num_rows > 0) {
                            $rowu = $resultu->fetch_assoc();
                            $balance = $rowu['ac_balanced'];
                            $new_balance = $balance - $_debtor + $_creditor;

                            $stmtu2 = $con->prepare("UPDATE categories SET ac_balanced=? WHERE acc_serial=? AND acc_name=? AND company=?");
                            $stmtu2->bind_param('ssss', $new_balance, $_acc_serial_token, $_account, $_SESSION["company"]);

                            if ($stmtu2->execute()) {
                                $stmt5 = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM jentress_erp WHERE id = ? AND company=?");
                                $stmt5->bind_param("is", $_id, $_SESSION["company"]);
                                if ($stmt5->execute()) {
                                    if (isset($_path) && file_exists($_path)) {
                                        unlink($_path);
                                    }
                                    echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){toastr.success("Entry successfully deleted");}) </script>';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){toastr.error("Error occurred while deleting the entry");}) </script>';
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){toastr.error("Error occurred while updating the balance");}) </script>';
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){toastr.error("No data found");}) </script>';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){toastr.error("Entry number error");}) </script>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){toastr.error("No data found for this number");}) </script>';
        }

        // After successful deletion, generate a new token
        $_SESSION['auth_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(20));
    }
}
?>

When trying to delete multiple entries in a single request or making successive delete requests within the same session, the CSRF token validation fails. The error message indicates a potential CSRF attack. This suggests that the CSRF token is being reused or is not being updated properly, causing subsequent requests to fail the CSRF check.
What I Need Help With:

Understanding why the CSRF token validation is failing when attempting to delete multiple entries.
Suggestions on how to properly handle CSRF tokens in such scenarios to ensure that multiple deletions can be performed in a single session without issues.


Totally unrelated to your problem but htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($antiXss->xss_clean is a code-smell. I mean no disrespect when I say this but I often see these as magic protection functions that are copied and pasted from codebase to codebase with the blind assumption that they make you safe, when in fact they often do more harm than good, and can very easily introduce bugs that make debugging a nightmare. You are using prepared statements, great job! That's the number one thing you should be doing. Then if you expect an int or date or other known type, test for that, and escape on output.

Also, you are sending toast messages in a while loop. If this does work with multiple eventually, sending 20 or 50 Entry successfully deleted messages to the client will be really annoying, really fast, so hopefully that's on your radar, too

The issue is that the CSRF token is not being changed; it remains the same, which results in a "CSRF attack detected" error. I checked the token during the initial deletion, and found it in the form's hidden field as c6b00ae070abef63b672d97f9034916a068d04a3. During the second deletion, I found the same token again in the form's hidden field as c6b00ae070abef63b672d97f9034916a068d04a3, which means the page was not refreshed or reloaded. Could the issue be resolved by refreshing or reloading the page to change the CSRF token?

Well, how are you submitting the form? I notice its in a modal, do you use javascript and ajax to submit? That would mean the page isn't refreshed.

Unless I'm mistaken, your script only accepts one ID for deletion at once.
Therefore if you're doing multiple deletions, it must mean you're making multiple different HTTP requests to this script. But a CSRF token is only valid for a single request.
In fact the last line of the script you've shown us is specifically generating a new token and placing it in the Session, overwriting the old one - although it doesn't appear to take any steps to return the token to the front-end...presumably you have another process for doing that implemented somewhere.
You need to ensure you get a new token and place it in your HTML form to use for each new request. Or you could consider re-designing your form and the PHP script so it can accept multiple IDs in one request.
